# How to build a Tkinter GUI in linux like exe in window?

Tags: linux, user-interface, tkinter, exe

I worote some Tkinter script in Linux,everytime I use "python script.py" to run it from terminal, but in windows,I can use pyinstaller to build an EXE file, then double click the GUI will run.
How do I do in linux to build an "exe" file then can click it will run instead of "python script.py"?

pyinstaller

Comment: You can use pyinstaller in Linux as well.

Comment: in Linux rather nobody use .exe file or similar. You could create package like .deb for Debian/Ubuntu/Mint, .rpm for RedHat/Fedora or simply create Python's package installed with `pip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux you can add `shebang` (`#!`) in first line of script

with full path to python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

or more popular (because different Linux may have Python in different folder)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

And set it executable

```
chmod +x script.py
```

and then you can run it as any other program by clicking or writhing in console `script.py` without `python`.

System will use information from `shebang` to run it with Python.

You can even remove extension or set different extension - even `.jpg` - and it should  run it with Python.

---

The same way you can create executable script with Bash, Perl, Ruby, ect. or even in PHP.

---

To find path to python, perl, etc

```
which python

which perl
```

---

`#` = `she` , `!` = `bang`, `#!` = `shebang`

Comment: Thanks Furas a lot for your details sharing.

Answer (score 2):

I am showing how to make a tkinter app executable in linux.

My Python file is /home/abhik/MyApp.py
My tkinter code is:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(root, text=Hello)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

First add a shebang in top of the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Then run in the terminal:

```
$ cd /home/abhik
$ chmod +x MyApp.py
```

To view it as an app:

```
$ cd /usr/share/applications
$ sudo gedit MyApp.desktop
```

In the gedit window enter this code:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Exec=/home/abhik/MyApp.py
Icon=/path/to/your/downloaded/icon/for/your/app
Name=<Name of your App>
Type=Application
```

Then save the file and reboot your system.

Then search for app. You will be able to see it.

Comment: You will have to search for the app by the name you gave in the MyApp.desktop file.